# Count mismatches between rows in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need some help on this cause I'm getting an issue

I've this three columns (Time, R1 and R2) and I'm trying to count the mismatches between R1 and R2 but for each month (on the time column)

I already used a formula but I'm having an issue to add 1.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bVP79Gbd14lO6xunu2K9POT7y55yrXegD-cTF70Fb4k/edit#gid=0   (the spreadsheet with the values)

```
=iferror(if(EOMONTH($A64,0)=$A64,SUMPRODUCT(month(Database!$C$2:$C) = month($A64),--(Database!G$2:G <> Database!H$2:H)),""),"Error")
```

This part "month(Database!$C$4:$C) = month($A5)" is where I compare the information of the months, ( but I'm having an issue cause cause "month(Database!$C$4:$C)" only retrieves 4 that is the month of april)

This part "(Database!G$4:G <> Database!H$4:H)" is where I compare the columns R1 and R2

The part "EOMONTH($A5,0)=$A5" is where I take the month to based myself

```
Time R1 R2

2020-04-30  BA  BU

2020-04-30  BU  BA

2020-04-29  BA  BU

2020-04-29  BU  BA

2020-04-28  BA  BU

2020-04-28  AA  BA

2020-04-25  AA  BA

2020-04-22  BU  BA

2020-04-19  AA  BU

2020-04-19  AA  BA

2020-03-27  BA  AA

2020-03-27  BA  AA

2020-03-26  BU  AA

2020-03-18  BA  AA

2020-03-18  AA  BU
```

Comment: What do you mean by:
>I already used a formula but I'm having an issue to add 1.
Your formula works fine on my [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11kn44uMETFBuvhsrzQKmxrjHE5RFJdM7KHfSsziRs1s/edit?usp=sharing)

- Did you format your time column as Date?

Comment: @Alessandro, thanks for the comment. my issue is when "month(Database!$C$4:$C) is always return 4, and them when the month is April, the value is right, but when its not, the value goes plus 1.  I will check now the date format to see if run on the good way

Comment: My mistake, the problem is cause I have dates from two different columns, I'll add on the question

Comment: I'll share a sheet with you, will be easier

Comment: Ok, put a link on your question.

Comment: I add on the question!

Comment: Please try not to [cross post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142556/count-mismatches-between-rows-in-google-sheet). If you do so, please let us know that you already have a solution so one does not have to expect a respond form you. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that!!!! My big apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach

In order to validate the answer I created a test Spreadsheet from a copy of your. In this sheet I created two support columns, one which contains the month number: `MONTH($A1)` and the other one a flag if the two values R1 and R2 are different: `IF($B1=$C1,"",1)`.

In this way I can use this two support structure to validate the numbers obtained by the formula which didn't use any. I will use a much simpler formula this time to compute the sum `=SUMIF(D:D,month(<DATE_VALUE>),E:E)`.

I will link [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wWplz2FauKzzSMtyKXa6OopvZWQVymLvwtQvya0Yzh4/edit?usp=sharing) the test sheet. As you can see the values are the same as the ones obtained by the formula. So, I can confirm that if you are expecting different results, your database is not consistent.

In conclusion the formula: `if(EOMONTH($A64,0)=$A64,SUMPRODUCT(month(Database!$C$2:$C) = month($A64),--(Database!G$2:G <> Database!H$2:H)),"")` is working correctly.

Comment: thank you so much!!!!! I'll take a look again on the database to see if i can correct it!!!!